# How to store a row of a dataframe into another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am iterating over rows of a dataFrame using for loop, after some operations I want to append the whole row to an empty dataframe and then append more rows from sf in the iterations. How to do it?

```py
for i in sf.index: 
    # sf is the name of dataframe object and mn 
    # is empty data frame before iteration
    mn.append(?)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
df = pd.DataFrame()   
for i,r in sf.iterrows():  
    df = df.append( r )
```